# mysql insert script works on localhost but won't work on server?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am using the following code which all works fine on my localhost and produces no errors except when I run the file from my server it does not insert the values into my table. I am not getting any errors.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$reference=$_GET['reference']; 
include '../../include/config.php';
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE new_supplier_request
        SET action_taken='actioned', status = 'Actioned', process_description = 'Supplier Contacted' WHERE reference = '$reference'";

mysql_select_db('hewden1');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}


$first = "SELECT * FROM new_supplier_request WHERE reference = '$reference'"; 
$result = mysql_query($first);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$user1 = substr($row['contact_second_name'], 0, 5) . '';
$user2 = substr($row['contact_first_name'], 0, 1) . '';
$digits = 2;
$num = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);


$digits2 = 8;
$ref = rand(pow(10, $digits2-1), pow(10, $digits2)-1);

$user = $user1.$user2.$num;


$comp_name = $row['company_name'];
$first_name = $row['contact_first_name'];
$second_name = $row['contact_second_name'];
$email = $row['contact_email'];
}

include '../../dependables/secure.php';  

$query = "INSERT INTO supplier_users(user_id, user_name, company_name, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_email, user_password_hash, salt, account_created)
VALUES ('".$ref."','".$user."','".$comp_name."','".$first_name."','".$second_name."','".$email."','".$hash."','".$salt."',now())";
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $conn);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO supplier_stats(user_id, user_name, company_name, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_email)  SELECT user_id, user_name, company_name, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_email FROM supplier_users WHERE user_id = '$ref' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conn);


include '../send_emails/send_email1.php';
mysql_close($conn);


if($result2) {

    $_SESSION['success'] = '<div id="bottom_notification"><div id="bottom_notification_heading"><h23>Request Received Successfully!</h23><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose">&#10006;</div></div><p>Thank you, the request was actioned successfully. Your reference is: '.$reference.'.</p><p><a href="track_request.php">Track this request.</a>.</div>';
    $_SESSION['message2'] = '<div class="message_box_prompt"><div class="boxclose2" id="boxclose2" style="float:right; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div><div class="message_box_text"><strong>Success!</strong> Your request was actioned successfully. Your reference is: '.$reference.'.</div></div>';
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }else{


    $_SESSION['success'] = '<div id="bottom_notification"><div id="bottom_notification_heading"><h23>There was a problem!</h23><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose">&#10006;</div></div><p>We had difficulty processing your request.</p><p><a href="track_request.php">Track this request.</a>.</div>';
    $_SESSION['message2'] = '<div class="message_box_prompt"><div class="boxclose2" id="boxclose2" style="float:right; margin:10px; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div><div class="message_box_text"><strong>Oooops!</strong> There was a problem processing your request.</div></div>';
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }

?>
```

Comment: You can do `mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error())` to see any error messages that come from MySQL.

Comment: Have you enabled error_reporting? place `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the very top of your file (just below the first <?php

Comment: @Epodax yes I have just done that and I am still getting no error

Comment: Hm, I think You need to change php.ini in your server or settings of your web-server. Probably some settings need to be amended. And It would be great if you glance at such thing as PDO